# How to get RecyclerView's Clicked data Position to View Pager Swipe?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I'm using Viewpager for slider and initially Recyclerview... When I load image from Server to recycler it's done... Now what i want to do that when ever someone click on particular item, it should be opened in second activity in which ViewPager I use.. example: When I click first Image, it should open that image in viewPager(slider).... And Also when someone swipe on ViewPager's activity it should load more images.... 
Code is Below and don't know what to do next. Please Help me.

RecyclerView

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.myViewHolder> {

ArrayList<model> mdata;
Context context;
public  RecyclerViewAdapter(){ }

public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<model> mdata, Context context) {
    this.mdata = mdata;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item,viewGroup,false);
    return new myViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final myViewHolder holder, int i) {


    Picasso.get().load(mdata.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getWallpaper()).into(holder.wallpaper);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent i = new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);

            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("wallpaperUrl",mdata.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getWallpaper());

            context.startActivity(i);

        }
    });



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mdata.size();
}

public  class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView wallpaper;
    Button set;

    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        wallpaper = itemView.findViewById(R.id.wallpaper);
        set = itemView.findViewById(R.id.set);
    }
}
```

Second Activity which have ViewPager:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);


  btn = findViewById(R.id.setWallpaper);
    mdata = new ArrayList<model>();
 viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    Integer[] colors_temp ={getResources().getColor(R.color.color1),
            getResources().getColor(R.color.color2),
            getResources().getColor(R.color.color3),
            getResources().getColor(R.color.color4),

    } ;

    colors = colors_temp;

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffSet, int pixels) {
            if (position < adapter.getCount() -1 &&  position <(colors.length) -1){

                viewPager.setBackgroundColor(
                        (Integer) argbEvaluator.evaluate
                                (positionOffSet,
                                        colors[position],
                                        colors[position + 1]));
            }else{
                viewPager.setBackgroundColor(colors[colors.length - 1]);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(final int i) {

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    DownloadImage downloadImage = new DownloadImage();
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;

                    try{

                       bitmap = 
    downloadImage.execute(mdata.get(i).getWallpaper()).get();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Something went 
               Wrong! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("wallpapers");

    mReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                model data = dataSnapshot1.getValue(model.class);
                mdata.add(data);

            }

            adapter = new Adapter(mdata,getApplicationContext());

            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Failed! "+databaseError, 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

  }
```

MyAdapter:

```
public class Adapter extends PagerAdapter {

ArrayList<model> mdata;
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public  Adapter(){

}

public Adapter(ArrayList<model> mdata, Context context) {
    this.mdata = mdata;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mdata.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
    return view.equals(o);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull final ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item,container,false);

    ImageView wallpaper;
    Button btn;

    wallpaper = view.findViewById(R.id.wallpaperImage);

    Picasso.get().load(mdata.get(position).getWallpaper()).into(wallpaper);

    container.addView(view,0);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
   container.removeView((View)object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your enter code here, add `setOnclickListener` to `holser.iytemView`, then create an intent for navigating to the second activity, and add this code in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: LoadingProfileActivity");
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            /*
              Extras
            */
            mainActivityContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

If you want to send the image or id that contained in this row add `intent.putExtra()` after the intent is created.

Like if I want to display the image in second activity ill put in

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("image_url", imageResource);
```

In SecondActivity firsts get the imageresource from the intent

```
String imageResouce = getIntent.getStringExtra("image_url");
```

Then display the image in image view

Comment: I did that but the there  isn't anything like imageview to display that image in second activity except  it contains ViewPager... Let me tell all the things are in the Adapter. So how do I pass that data between Recycler view to that Adapter according to your code. I know that code but i didn't understand how to implement in this case. Please let me know, more about how to achieve that.

Comment: check this project that i created for you    [Github Project] (https://github.com/AshwithJoylan/ScrollImages)

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the images from the server, and each image has an id, pass the id into then intent. When you open up the view that needs the image that was clicked, make a service call to retrieve the image from the server using it's id.